# CSS animation with js

Tags: javascript, css, html

I wanted to make a piece of code which makes it so that when you drag an element onto another, a CSS animation starts. Here is the link  http://NoobCode.repl.co/Cryptage

When you drag the key on the cadenas you get an alert with a link. On the link there is a little animation. I'd like this animation to start when I drag the key on the cadena. I searched, but it doesn't seem possible to make it start with a function.

Comment: So you dont want the alert?

Answer (score 0):

Use your script to add a class to the element you want to animate.

In your CSS:

```
.accordion {
  ... whatever style
}
.accordion.animate {
  animation css here
}
```

Comment: Im not sure to understand. When the key is droped it start a function. at the same time , but i want the animation to start too. could you be more clear please ?

Comment: `.accordion.animate {
  animation: 500ms accordionAnimation forwards;
}
@keyframes accordionAnimation {
  from: {opacity: 0;}
  to: {opacity: 1;}
}`